# Can I split a SQL table into three classes using EF 6.1 and SQL Server 2012?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following class which I simplified for this example. The class has an id 
and some properties related to House and some related to room. All the data is stored
in one row of a SQL table.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.Models
{
    public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AdminHouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string AdminHouseCity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AdminRoomNumber { get; set; }
        public string AdminRoomFloor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [AdminHouseNumber]     INT            NULL,
    [AdminHouseCity]       NCHAR (10)     NULL,
    [AdminRoomNumber]      INT            NULL,
    [AdminRoomFloor]       NCHAR (10)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

This maps to my database like this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.Models.Mapping
{
    public class AspNetUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUser>
    {
        public AspNetUserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(128);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            this.Property(t => t.AdminHouseNumber).HasColumnName("AdminHouseNumber");
            this.Property(t => t.AdminHouseCity).HasColumnName("AdminHouseCity");
            this.Property(t => t.AdminRoomNumber).HasColumnName("AdminRoomNumber");
            this.Property(t => t.AdminRoomFloor).HasColumnName("AdminRoomFloor");
        }
    }
}
```

For performance reasons I would like to keep all my data in the one table. However is
it possible for me to create two additional classes. One for house and one for room
and have all three classes link to the same table?

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.Models
{
    public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string RoomId { get; set; }
        public string HouseId { get; set; }
        public virtual House { get; set; }
        public virtual Room { get; set; }

       public class House
           public string HouseId { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> AdminHouseNumber { get; set; }
           public string AdminHouseCity { get; set; }
       }

       Public class Room
           public string RoomId { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> AdminRoomNumber { get; set; }
           public string AdminRoomFloor { get; set; }
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is called ComplexTypes support, some googling showed [this basic article](http://soabubblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/cf-configuring-complex-types/)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as that you have three types of AspNetUser; AspNetUser, House and Room.  If I'm wrong, then this answer will not make sense - please let me know.

You may want to look at using Table per Hierarchy Inheritance in your modelling, but that will require a further "flag column" in your table to work (for example containing 0 for AspNetUser, 1 for House, 2 for Room).  I've found that performance is slightly slower when using TPH, but essentially you do this.

```
public class AspNetUserBase
{
    //Define columns shared between all here
}

public class AspNetUser: AspNetUserBase
{
    // Define columns only for AspNetUser here
}

public class House: AspNetUserBase
{
    // Define columns only for House here
}

// Repeat for Room

// Now define the "split" in OnModelCreating
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Any code you need etc.

    // This part maps all three to the table
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserBase>()
      .Map<AspNetUser>(m => m.Requires("Your Flag Column").HasValue(0)) // 0 is example
      .Map<House>(m => m.Requires("Your Flag Column").HasValue(1)) // 1 is example
      .Map<Room>(m => m.Requires("Your Flag Column").HasValue(2)) // 2 is example
}
```

You'll then be able to directly perform CRUD's on AspNetUser, Home or Room (without having to reference the base class).

However, I've got to question the need for them all to be on one table for performance reasons as my experience has almost always proved otherwise.  It's hard to be specific as of course I don't know your entire model, but I urge at some point you re-evaluate.